# influence of categorical variables on a quantitative continuous variable

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, categorical-data, random-forest, interaction

I have the next dataset:

-Day(7 levels)

-Channel (15 levels)

-DayPart(4 levels)

-Spot(2 levels)

-Format(2 levels)

-Visits (continuous variable)

Can someone give me an advice wich method to use in order to find which factors (Day, Channel, DayPart, Spot,Format) influence my continuous variable (Visits), taking into account their possible interections?

I've already tried linear regression,

```
model<-lm(Visits ~ Day * Channel * DayPart * Spot * Format, data=source)
```

but the model explain (p<0.05) only a few of interections, does it mean that all others do not have any influence on number of visits? I also get negative coefficients fot those interections who are significant. Does it really mean that this factors decrese the number of visitors? All this regarding that R-squared is low: 31%

I've also tried a RandomForest using R package:

```
fit2 <- randomForest(Visits ~ Day + Channel + Spot + Format + DayPart , importance=T, data = train, mtry=5)
```

But applying fit2 to test data subset I get to much discrepancies between real and predicted number of visits.

Comment: I would have thought that trying to fit a five-way interaction was optimistic. Try restricting yourself to all the two-ways first. If your outcome is a count you might consider swapping to Poisson regression.

Comment: thank you mdewey for your advise! But if I understand correctly, 2-way interections will always niglect 3 others factors. this will help me just to identify wich factor influence more or less on the output, I guess. But my order is to "rank"/sort all levels interections

Comment: Have you ever tried to explain to someone what a three-way interaction means, let alone a five-way?